# Not being able to concat slices

Tags: go

I have the following code, which is returning 4 slices, and I'd like to make it one.

```
 var postArray []string

        if strings.Contains(s.Text(), "k") || greaterThan(voteValue) {
            postArray = append(postArray, s.Text())
        }

        for _, p := range postArray {
            postArray = append(postArray, p...)
            fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(p))
        }

        fmt.Println(postArray)
```

I'm not posting the whole code because I guess that it won't be needed, the slices returned are these ones:

[31.8k], [3151], [50.5k], [8111], but I'd like to get [31.8k 3151 50.5k 8111]. The p variable is a string, so I get the following error:

cannot use p (type string) as type []string in append

I've tried some things but didn't suceed, hope someone can point me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: My goal is to create a []string with the slices that are being returned. Like, I've got 4 slices but I want just one slice with all the other slices, like [value1 value2], and not [value1] [value2] for instance. If I wasn't clear feel free to ask again, I'm new to Go :P

Comment: Remove the `...` (three dots) after `p` from `postArray = append(postArray, p...)`. That should remove the error. The `...` are used to expand slices (or string when appending to byte slices), and `p` is string being appended to slice to strings.

Comment: I've already tried that, it returns the same number of slices but with repeated values, like:

[50.5k 50.5k]

Maybe it's a logic failure from my side that I'm not being able to see...

Comment: It does compile, but It doesn't produces the output I want

Comment: I was getting the error when I had the ..., if I remove it, it does work, but it returns me multiple slices, and I'd like to make them all into a unique slice. I guess that it may have something to due with my if condition, that is creating a slice everytime that the condition is true. But this isn't the scope of the question anymore, so I'd have to edit mine or accept the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clearly the way you are appending in your loop will not result in the kinda list you want.

```
postArray = append(postArray, p...)  // you are appending a vector here which you don't want in your case
```

instead use this,

```
postArray = append(postArray, p)
```

Comment: I've already tried that, it returns the same number of slices but with repeated values, like: [50.5k 50.5k]. It may be due to my if condition, it seems to be creating a slice every time that the condition is true.